# How many subsets of a set with $100$ elements have more than $2$ element?

Tags: combinatorics

Question

> How many subsets of a set with $100$ elements have more than $2$ element?

Approach

Number of subsets of a set with $100$ elements =$2^{100}$

Number of subsets of a set with $100$ elements having more than $2$ element

=$2^{100}$-Number of subsets of a set with $100$ elements having **less** than $2$ element$(X)$

$X$=Number of subsets of a set with $100$ elements having no element $( \phi) $+
Number of subsets of a set with $100$ elements having one element 
=1+100

Hence,

**Number of subsets of a set with $100$ elements having more than $2$ element**=

$2^{100}-101$

Am I right?

Comment: Thank you, but the question says less fewer than one element and not fewer than 2 elements. Please correct me if I am wrong. And why we did not say that it's $2^{100}-2^{10}$ since in case we have one element, it can be in or not in the 1 element sets, so the answer should be 100 to be in and 100 to not be in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong. You forgot to include sets with **exactly** two elements.

The correct formula would be

Number of subsets = Number of sets with more than 2 elements + number of sets with 2 elements + number of sets with less than 2 elements.

Comment: will the answer be $2^{100}-101-\binom{100}{2}$ =$2^{100}-101-4950$
 ? isn't it?

Comment: @laura Yup, that's the answer!

Comment: Thank you, but the question says less fewer than one element and not fewer than 2 elements. Please correct me if I am wrong. And why we did not say that it's $2^{100}-2^{10}$ since in case we have one element, it can be in or not in the 1 element sets, so the answer should be 100 to be in and 100 to not be in?

Comment: @Avra I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Why do you think $2^{100}-2^{10}$ would be the correct result? Also, what do you mean by "the question says less fewer than one element"? Where does the question say that?

Comment: @5xum. I meant to say since we are asked about integers with one element, that should not include 2 elements as you subtracted the two elements possibilites, so it should be only $2^{100}-101$. Please correct me if I am wrong/

Comment: @Avra Where in the question does the text say anything about "integers with one element"? Where does the question say anything about integers at all? Also, what do you mean when you say you "subtracted the two element possibilities"? There are ${100\choose 2}$ two-element possibilities. Where in the expression "$2^{100}-101$ did you subtract those possibilities?

Comment: @5xum. Based on answer $2^{100}-101-  {100 \choose 2}$. As you see ${100}\choose{2}$ was subtracted. Is it because "more than" indicates that 2 is not inclusive, so we subtract ${100 \choose 2}$?

Comment: @Avra Exactly, which is exactly what my answer is all about.

Comment: @Avra The point is that a set with exactly two elements does **not** have more than 2 elements. Because $2$ is **not** more than $2$.